# given a symmetric matrix $A_{n\times n}$ and integer $m$, is there any matrix $X_{n\times m}$, s.t., $X\times X^{t}=A$?

Tags: matrix-equations, matlab, matrix-decomposition, python

Recently I've come across the following problem. I would be very pleased if someone helps me how to deal with.
given a symmetric matrix $A_{n\times n}$($n$ is fixed) and positive integer $m$, is there any matrix $X_{n\times m}$, s.t., $X\times X^{t}=A$?
My further questions are:

1. If the question has an answer, how many would they be?
2. Can I solve it with the aid of powerful software like Matlab or Python?

Comment: Look for Cholesky decomposition for the case $m=n$

Comment: @FormulaWriter, Yes $A$ is symmetric.